# Where is this used in programming -->(')

Tags: vim

I thinking of mapping single quotation mark to double quotation mark i.e `' -> "` in my vimrc.

Besides declaring chars in C, where is `'` is used in programming?

Should I map it?
I'll reverse map them to access both.

Comment: No, don't map it. I think you will cause more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It's used in PHP, when programmers want their SQL statements to be hacked by outsiders.

Comment: If I don't do PHP, I am fine?

Comment: Seriously, cross that bridge when you get to it.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?  Is your shift key broken, or your fingers fatigued?

Comment: Trust me, this will serious problem next time. I even dont buy keyboard which has \\ at different position than the position I am used to. Severe productivity loss!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes are used *all over the place* in programming.

- In the Bourne shell (and derivatives, and `csh` and derivatives, and `Perl` and other languages) it is used to inhibit string exansion, so you can do this:

  ```
  $ echo '$VARIABLE'
  $VARIABLE
  ```
- In `C`, the single quote is used to denote a character constant, rather than a string.  So you can do this:

  ```
  char c = 'c';
  ```

  But this is an error:

  ```
  char c = "c";
  ```
- And of course if you are programming in a language called "English", the single quote is used to denote important things like possessives ("snihalani's question seemed sort of odd) as well as contractions ("I can't believe anyone would want to do this.").

These are just a few examples.  There are, of course, more.

Comment: Not to mention prose or strings with single quotes. I can't think of any ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I use single quotes almost exclusively. They're useful when you're using double quotes inside of strings:

```
print 'Foo said, "Bar"'
```

It's easier than escaping them:

```
print "Foo said, \"Bar\""
```

Also, you won't be able to type normal sentences with possessives either:

```
# Attaches foo's signal to a slot
self.foo.bar.connect(self.baz)
```

PHP, for instance, doesn't perform variable substitution when strings are quoted with single quotes:

```
$var = 1;
echo('I will literally print $var');
```

Answer (score 1):

In many languages (e.g., C, C++, Ada), `'` delimits character literals and `"` delimits string literals.

In others (e.g., Perl, Bourne shell), either `'` or `"` can be used for string literals, but with different semantics; `"` is handy when the string contains `'` characters, and vice versa, and `"` causes references to variables to be expanded to the name of the variable, while `'` prevents this.

Ada uses `'` to delimit the name of an attribute.

And in *all* languages, you'll need `'` in comments and string literals -- for example if you want to write "you'll need `'` in comments and string literals".

They're distinct characters.  Removing your ability to type one of them is Not A Good Idea.

You might consider mapping `'` to `"` *and vice versa*, if that makes typing easier for you.  But once you get into the habit of using your mappings, it could be awkward to use somebody else's setup, or to type text into something other than vim.